# Another way to see the behaviour of $||u||_p$ when $p\to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Consider the functionals defined by $$\Phi_p(u):=\left\lbrace\dfrac{1}{\vert \Omega\vert}\int_{\Omega}\vert u\vert^p \, \mathsf{d}x\right\rbrace^{1/p},$$ for $p\neq 0$. I want check the well known result $$\lim_{p\to 0}\Phi_p(u)=\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert}\int\log\vert u\vert \, \mathsf{d}x\right).$$ I know that there is an increasing sequence of elementary functions $(u)_n$ such that $\int_\Omega u_n\to\int_\Omega u$. Now by using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560417/lim-p-to-0-left-sum-n-1n-lambda-na-np-right1-p-exp-left-sum-n/2560499?noredirect=1#comment5285419_2560499) the assertion holds true for any $u_n$, i.e.

$$\lim_{p\to 0}\Phi_p(u_n)=\exp\left(\dfrac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert}\int\log\vert u_n\vert \, \mathsf{d}x\right).$$
My problem is the following...

Is the equality 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{p\to 0}\Phi_p(u_n)=\lim_{p\to 0}\lim_{n\to \infty}\Phi_p(u_n)$$ true? If it is we finished. Can you help me?

Comment: look here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115428/limit-of-lp-norm-when-p-to0